# How to add additional variable to pytest html report

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, pytest

I am using `pytest` HTML report plugin for my selenium tests.
It works great with just passing `test.py --html==report.htmlin` command line and generates a great report.

I also need to implement additional string/variable to each test case display. It doesn't matter if it's pass or failed it should just show "ticket number". This ticket id I can return in each test scenario.

I could just add ticket number to test name, but it will look ugly.

Please advise what's the best way to do it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

You can insert custom HTML for each test by either adding HTML content to the "show details" section of each test, or customizing the result table (e.g. add a ticket column).

The first possibility is the simplest, you can just add the following to your `conftest.py`:

```py
@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    pytest_html = item.config.pluginmanager.getplugin('html')
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    extra = getattr(report, 'extra', [])
    if report.when == 'call':
        extra.append(pytest_html.extras.html('<p>some html</p>'))
        report.extra = extra
```

Where you can replace `<p>some html</p>` with your content.

The second solution would be:

```py
@pytest.mark.optionalhook
def pytest_html_results_table_header(cells):
    cells.insert(1, html.th('Ticket'))


@pytest.mark.optionalhook
def pytest_html_results_table_row(report, cells):
    cells.insert(1, html.td(report.ticket))


@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    report.ticket = some_function_that_gets_your_ticket_number()
```

Remember that you can always access the current test with the item object, this might help retrieving the information you need.

Comment: Hi nice one , which module should import for 'html'?

Comment: @user1181979 `from py.xml import html`

Comment: Can the same thing be done for this pytest-html report? https://pypi.org/project/pytest-html-reporter/