# pytest-html Customizing Result table with output from test results

Tags: python, pytest, python-unittest, pytest-html

I am trying to do API automation using pytest. I want to include status_code as one of the columns in the report html generated using pytest-html. I collected the status_code in one variable in test function. But how to pass it to hook in conftest.

My unit test file has below code.

```
class Test1(unittest.TestCase):
    def test1_cust_list_page(self):
        cust_list_resp = requests.post(BASE_URL+customer_list_ep,json=cust_page_payload,headers=headers,params=cust_list_params)
        print(cust_list_resp.status_code)
        status_code = cust_list_resp.status_code
        assert cust_list_resp.status_code==200
```

My conftest file has the below code:

```
from datetime import datetime
from py.xml import html
import pytest

@pytest.mark.optionalhook
def pytest_html_results_table_header(cells):
    cells.insert(2, html.th('Status_code'))
    cells.insert(1, html.th('Time', class_='sortable time', col='time'))
    cells.pop()

@pytest.mark.optionalhook
def pytest_html_results_table_row(report, cells):
    cells.insert(2, html.td(report.status_code))
    cells.insert(1, html.td(datetime.utcnow(), class_='col-time'))
    cells.pop()

@pytest.mark.hookwrapper
def pytest_runtest_makereport(item, call):
    outcome = yield
    report = outcome.get_result()
    report.status_code = str(item.function.)
```

What the code should be in the last line, if I want to invoke value of status_code from test1_cust_list_page unit test.

I refer to the below stack , but the second option is not clear to which function to be called .
[How to add additional variable to pytest html report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43241640/how-to-add-additional-variable-to-pytest-html-report)

Comment: Just after reading your question, I got the answer of my question that "how to remove column from this results table?" Thanks! :)

Answer (score -1):

## Use an extra parameter in your test case like

```py
def test1_cust_list_page(self, request)
     #---other piece of code written here---
     #assign the variable the value within the test as
     request.node._status_code=cust_list_resp.status_code
     #in the above statement you created a variable _status_code
```

Now in the html results table hook

```py
@pytest.mark.optionalhook
def pytest_html_results_table_row(report, cells):
    #access your variable like below
    cells.insert(2, html.td(report._status_code))
```

Conclusion

> Value contained in report._status_code in conftest.py file is same as request.node._status_code in the test file